# develop Haskell code with vim and haskelmode plugin

Tags: haskell, vim, haskell-mode

I have a silly question, I'm sure, I use vim with haskell-mode plugin to develop on haskell but I'm not sure how to enable the keys combination define on the haskellmode -vim, for example:

> |_ct| create |tags| file
>
> |_si| show info for id under cursor
>
> |_t| show type for id under cursor
>
> |_T| insert type declaration for id under cursor |balloon| show type
>   for id under mouse pointer
>
> |_?| browse Haddock entry for id under cursor
>
> |_?1| search Hoogle for id under cursor
>
> |_?2| search Hayoo! for id under cursor

how to type a command on vim that start with '_' (I know there said that this represent cursor and than I suppose that I just have to type 'si' for that field but nothing is happened) on which mode have to type it, I suppose on normal mode. I work on Mac but the same problem I have on linux.

Thanks
Sorin.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/lukerandall/haskellmode-vim/blob/master/doc/haskellmode.txt#L242):

```
Finally, the mappings actually use <LocalLeader> behind the scenes, so if
you have to, you can redefine maplocalleader to something other than '_'.
Just remember that the docs still refer to mappings starting with '_', to
avoid confusing the majority of users!-)
```

So you must press <kbd>_</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd> in rapid succession to create a `tags` file for your project.

Unless you have set your `<LocalLeader>` to something other than `_`.